# Crack the (Poorly Designed) Safe

Tags: combinatorics

The brilliant engineers at ACME industries have created what they think is a very secure safe. There are $9$ switches, each with three settings (high, low, and off). However, these engineers are lazy, and only $2$ of these switches actually do anything! The safe will open when a lever is pulled while these two switches are in a certain, secret setting. The "security" of this safe relies on the fact that nobody knows which pair of switches are the functional ones.

The engineers believe that anyone trying to open the safe would potentially have to try all $3^{9}$ possible settings of the switches. Your task: make fools of them by showing how to crack the safe in just $15$ guesses.

**Source:** *Puzzling Adventures*, by Dennis E. Shasha.

Additional challenge: What is the fewest number of guesses you need? I don't know the answer.

Comment: Is a blowtorch considered a guess? ;)

Comment: Wouldn't it take a mere 324 guesses to brute force this safe, rather than the "brilliant" engineers' 3^9?

Comment: If all of the switches mattered, there are 3 options for 9 switches so 3^9 would be the amount needed for testing.

Comment: @CalebBernard Yes indeed, the engineers are wrong on many levels :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a method to crack the safe in 15 moves:

> The three settings can be represented as 0, 1, or 2. The possibilities that can open the safe are then 00, 11, 22, 01, 10, 02, 20, 12, and 21.

Step 1:

> Test the combinations of all 9 switches at 0, 1, and 2 for a total of 3 guesses. If none of these work, that eliminates the first 3 potential cases.

Step 2:

> Test these cases: (012012012, 120120120, 201201201) and (021021021, 210210210, 102102102). Any two positions chosen that aren't apart by multiples of 3 have every combination tested. If the safe still isn't opened by now, then the two switches are in the same position in the triplet.

Step 3:

> Test these cases: (000111222, 111222000, 222000111) and (000222111, 222111000, and 111000222). These cases test all the cases for the switches being apart by multiples of 3. After the last test case (guess #15), every possible combination has been tested for any pair of switches.

Note:

> I'm fairly certain 15 is the lowest number of guesses needed to guarantee a solution.

Comment: Correct, very well done!

Comment: Do you know what the optimal answer is for $n$ switches with $k$ settings, still with only 2 switches doing something? I know that you can get the minimum of $k^2$ if $n \leq k$ and $k$ is prime.

Comment: It seems like it would depend on other factors like if k is a multiple of n and of course which is bigger.

Comment: @xnor With $4$ switches, and $3$ settings, you can succeed in $9$ guesses (exercise left to reader).

Answer (score 2):

I think Quark's answer is correct, so I decided to think about a slight variation: what is the quickest way to get into the safe (rather than fewest guesses)? So consider this a bonus answer.

I make 2 assumptions:

1. moving a switch by 1 position and pulling the "guess" lever both take 1 unit of time.
2. moving a row of switches that are all in the same position takes the same amount of time as moving just one of them (because you can push them all with your hand at the same time).

Here is my method to get into the safe AQAP: It takes 59 switch flips and 51 lever pulls (pull the lever after every switch except for all 1's, after the first time) for a total of 110 units of time. I think the unit of time would be no more than a second, and so I can get into the safe in 2 minutes tops.

222222222
111111111
000000000
011111111
022222222 
122222222
111111111
100000000
200000000
211111111
221111111
220000000
110000000
111111111
112222222
002222222
001111111
000111111
000222222
111222222
111111111
111000000
222000000
222111111
222211111
222200000
111100000
111111111
111122222
000022222
000011111
000001111
000002222
111112222
111111111
111110000
222220000
222221111
222222111
222222000
111111000
111111111
111111222
000000222
000000111
000000011
000000022
111111122
111111111
111111100
222222200
222222211
222222221
222222220
111111110
111111111
111111112
000000002
000000001

Comment: This is a whole other can of worms!

Answer (score 1):

> The mistake the engineers made is not requiring all other switches to be off at the time the two 'secret' switches are in the correct state. This means that we can test multiple combinations with each pull of the lever. So...
>
> - There are 36 distinct pairs of switches.
>  - For each pair, there are nine combinations that need to be checked
>  - (OO, OL, OH, LO, LL, LH, HO, HL, HH)
>
> ...which works out to 324 per line. With three guesses, we can cover all the matching pairs for the entire thing:
>
> `OOOOOOOOO`
>
>  `LLLLLLLLL`
>
>  `HHHHHHHHH`
>
>
>  We need only six to make sure all adjacent pairs are covered, and we can do it by solving the first 2 switches and repeating the pattern:
>
> `OLOLOLOLO`
>
>  `OHOHOHOHO`
>
>  `LOLOLOLOL`
>
>  `LHLHLHLHL`
>
>  `HOHOHOHOH`
>
>  `HLHLHLHLH`
>
> ...which conveniently hits all the 'odd' non-adjacent pairs; since 1-2 is complete, the repeating pattern means (1-4, 1-6, and 1-8) will be as well. Same for (2-3, 2-5, 2-7, 2-9), but reversed, and the sets continue with (3-4, 3-6, 3-8), (4-5, 4-7, 4-9), (5-6, 5-8), (6-7, 6-9), (7-8), (8-9). That's 20 of the 36 pairs done so far.
>
> Now we make sure the even pairs are OK. Same pattern, but fill each line by skipping one and wrapping once:
>
> `OLLOOLLOO`
>
>  `OHHOOHHOO`
>
>  `LOOLLOOLL`
>
>  `HOOHHOOHH`
>
>  `LHHLLHHLL`
>
>  `HLLHHLLHH`
>
> This gives us (1-3, 1-5, 1-7, 1-9), (2-4, 2-6, 2-8), (3-5, 3-7, 3-9), (4-6, 4-8), (5-7, 5-9), (6-8), (7-9) -- the remaining 16.

EDIT: There's a mathematical way to express this; this was assuming that when cracking the safe, I temporarily become an innumerate monkey. If I can think of it, I'll come back and bolt it on.

Comment: Your method doesn't work when the leftmost and rightmost switches are the function ones, and their settings are different.